# How to Replicate RSA Authentication from Node.js in Flutter?

Tags: node.js, flutter, dart, rsa

I have the code below working in node.js and I am trying to convert it to make the API call directly from my flutter app, but I am having problems with the RSA encryption.

```js
import fetch from "node-fetch";
import nodeRSA from "node-rsa";

const KEYVER = '23'
const ID = '123456789123456789'
const PRIVATE_KEY = "vvkmlkmmvcmemmcmdmdmm.......cddncndndncn ="

generateRequestHeader(){
const hashString = `${ID}\n{Date.now().toString()}\n{KEYVER}\n`;
const signer = new nodeRSA(PRIVATE_KEY, "pkcs1");
const signature = signer.sign(hasString);
const sign_enc = signature.toString("base64");

return {
    "AUTH_SIGNATURE": sign_enc,
    "TIMESTAMP": Date.now().toString(),
    "ID": ID,
    "KEY_VERSION":KEYVER
  };
}

async function callAPI(){
  const options = {
     method: 'GET',
     headers: generateRequestHeader()
 };

 const response = await fetch(url, options);
 return response;
}
```

The authentication works fine in Node.js but I can't seem to find a package to replicate it in flutter. I was recommended *fast_rsapackage*:

```dart
#fast_rsa: ^3.4.6
import 'package:fast_rsa/fast_rsa.dart';

 class Signature{
   String Id = 'c93e7094-327b-4ff3-bf2e-c52f29a8277f';
   String privateKey = "ABCDEG....Z=";
   String keyVer = '23.0';

   generateRequestHeaders() async {
      String timeStamp = DateTime.now().toString();
      String hashString = "${Id}\n${timeStamp}\n${keyVer}\n";


     var signer = await RSA.convertPrivateKeyToPKCS1(privateKey);
     var signature = await RSA.signPKCS1v15(signer, Hash.SHA256, privateKey);
     var signature_enc = await RSA.base64(signature);

     return {

         "AUTH_SIGNATURE": signature_enc,
         "TIMESTAMP": timeStamp,
         "ID": Id,
         "KEY_VERSION": keyVer,
    };
 }

 Future<dynamic> rsaRequest() async {
    var options = {'method': 'GET', 'headers': generateRequestHeaders()};

   String url = 'https://api.........';
   http.Response response = await http.get(url, headers: options);

   try {
     if (response.statusCode == 200) {
       print(response.body);
       var document = parse(response.body);
       return document;
    } else {
      return "failed";
    }
  } catch (exp) {
    print(exp);
    return "failed";
  }
 }
  
}
```

But the server keeps returning *auth_error*.

How do I use the *.js* function directly inside flutter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I focus on the signing part. The NodeJS code creates a signature using RSA. For padding and digest the node-rsa default values are applied: PKCS#1v1.5 padding and SHA256, s. [here](https://github.com/rzcoder/node-rsa#options). The private key is imported as DER encoded PKCS#1 key (Base64 encoded). The signature is Base64 encoded.

Note that in the NodeJS code posted in the question, the `$` signs for the 2nd and 3rd variables regarding `hashString` are missing, which is probably a copy/paste error. This must be fixed, otherwise the signatures will differ!

On the Dart side, the following fixes are needed:

- The PKCS#1 key is to be passed *directly* to `RSA.signPKCS1v15()`, i.e. the `RSA.convertPrivateKeyToPKCS1()` call is to be removed. `RSA.signPKCS1v15()` expects a PEM encoded key, i.e. header and footer are to be added and in the Base64 encoded body there is a line break after every 64 characters.
- The timestamp is to be converted to the format used in the NodeJS code: `DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString()`.
- `RSA.signPKCS1v15()` returns the signature already base64 encoded, i.e. the `RSA.base64()` call must be removed.

A possible dart counterpart with the fast_rsa library that fixes the above issues is:

```dart
Future<Map<String,String>> generateRequestHeaders() async {
    String privateKey = '''-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBOwIBAAJBANoHbFSEZoOSB9Kxt7t8PoBwmauaODjECHqJgtTU3h4MW5K3857+
04Flc6x6a9xxyvCKS5RtOP2gaOlOVtrph0ECAwEAAQJBALu8LpRr2RWrdV7/tfQT
HIJd8oQnbAe9DIvuwh/fF08IwApOE/iGL+Ded49eoHHu1OXycZhpHavN/sQMnssP
FNECIQDyDIW7V5UUu16ZAeupeQ7zdV6ykVngd0bb3FEn99EchQIhAOaYe3ll211q
SIXVjKHudMn3xe6Vvguc9O7cwCB+gyqNAiEAsr3kk6/de23SMZNlf8TR8Z8eyybj
BAuQ3BMaKzWpyjECIFMR0UFNYTYIyLF12aCoH2h2mtY1GW5jj5TQ72GFUcktAiAf
WWXnts7m8kZWuKjfD0MQiW+w4iAph+51j+wiL3EMAQ==
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----''';
    String  keyVer = "23";
    String  Id = "123456789123456789";
    String timeStamp = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString(); // "1649917884089" for testing
    String hashString = "${Id}\n${timeStamp}\n${keyVer}\n";
    String signature = await RSA.signPKCS1v15(hashString, Hash.SHA256, privateKey);
    return {
        "AUTH_SIGNATURE": signature,
        "TIMESTAMP": timeStamp,
        "ID": Id,
        "KEY_VERSION": keyVer,
    };
}
...
var result = await generateRequestHeaders();
print(result["AUTH_SIGNATURE"]); // nRuX6eY+66Ca2ZbB/ZK6ealRdS8gYJ4UKNwUOdJySqujGnwpflE8aZ45L4PfQK3qAMJh02o0SVG8uy2Mz+BFpg== for datetime = '1649917884089'
```

---

Test:
Since signing with PKCS#1 v1.5 is deterministic, the *same* input data provides the *same* signature. This makes it easy to check the functional equivalence of both codes. If the same timestamp is used in both codes (e.g. the commented out `1649917884089`), both codes return the same signature (`nRuX6eY+66Ca2ZbB/ZK6ealRdS8gYJ4UKNwUOdJySqujGnwpflE8aZ45L4PfQK3qAMJh02o0SVG8uy2Mz+BFpg==`), which proves the equivalence of both codes.

This is the fixed NodeJS code used for the test. It is essentially the same as the NodeJS code posted in the question:

```js
// DER encoded PKCS#1 key, Base64 encoded
// Note: For testing purposes, a 512 bits key is used. In practice, key sizes >= 2048 bits must be applied for security reasons!
const PRIVATE_KEY = "MIIBOwIBAAJBANoHbFSEZoOSB9Kxt7t8PoBwmauaODjECHqJgtTU3h4MW5K3857+04Flc6x6a9xxyvCKS5RtOP2gaOlOVtrph0ECAwEAAQJBALu8LpRr2RWrdV7/tfQTHIJd8oQnbAe9DIvuwh/fF08IwApOE/iGL+Ded49eoHHu1OXycZhpHavN/sQMnssPFNECIQDyDIW7V5UUu16ZAeupeQ7zdV6ykVngd0bb3FEn99EchQIhAOaYe3ll211qSIXVjKHudMn3xe6Vvguc9O7cwCB+gyqNAiEAsr3kk6/de23SMZNlf8TR8Z8eyybjBAuQ3BMaKzWpyjECIFMR0UFNYTYIyLF12aCoH2h2mtY1GW5jj5TQ72GFUcktAiAfWWXnts7m8kZWuKjfD0MQiW+w4iAph+51j+wiL3EMAQ=="
const KEYVER = '23';
const ID = '123456789123456789';
const timeStamp = Date.now().toString(); // '1649917884089' for testing

function generateRequestHeader(){
    const hashString = `${ID}\n${timeStamp}\n${KEYVER}\n`; // Fix: Add the $ sign
    const signer = new nodeRSA(PRIVATE_KEY, "pkcs1");
    const signature = signer.sign(hashString); // default signing scheme: PKCS#1 v1.5 with SHA256
    const sign_enc = signature.toString("base64");    
    return {
        "AUTH_SIGNATURE": sign_enc,
        "TIMESTAMP": Date.now().toString(),
        "ID": ID,
        "KEY_VERSION":KEYVER
    };
}
...
var result = generateRequestHeader();
console.log(result.AUTH_SIGNATURE); // nRuX6eY+66Ca2ZbB/ZK6ealRdS8gYJ4UKNwUOdJySqujGnwpflE8aZ45L4PfQK3qAMJh02o0SVG8uy2Mz+BFpg== for datetime = '1649917884089'
```

Comment: Very very helpful. Any other package you might recommend that can do the same thing?

Comment: Signing/verifying with RSA and PKCS#1 v1.5 is a standard supported by most crypto libraries, e.g. [*PointyCastle*](https://github.com/bcgit/pc-dart/blob/master/tutorials/rsa.md#standards-supported) or [*encrypt*](https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt#signature-and-verification), a high level *PointyCastle* wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

you can use https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt package to perform `RSA` encryption and decryption in dart and flutter.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart';
import 'package:pointycastle/asymmetric/api.dart';

void main() {
  final publicKey = await parseKeyFromFile<RSAPublicKey>('test/public.pem');
  final privKey = await parseKeyFromFile<RSAPrivateKey>('test/private.pem');

  final plainText = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit';
  final encrypter = Encrypter(RSA(publicKey: publicKey, privateKey: privKey));

  final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(plainText);
  final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(encrypted);

  print(decrypted); // Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
  print(encrypted.base64); // kO9EbgbrSwiq0EYz0aBdljHSC/rci2854Qa+nugbhKjidlezNplsEqOxR+pr1RtICZGAtv0YGevJBaRaHS17eHuj7GXo1CM3PR6pjGxrorcwR5Q7/bVEePESsimMbhHWF+AkDIX4v0CwKx9lgaTBgC8/yJKiLmQkyDCj64J3JSE=
}
```

Comment: test/public.pem always says no such file or directory where i have the file.